# Octave / Matlab : Determine unique rows in very large matrix

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a 13146 x 13146 matrix in Octave whose unique rows I want to determine. `unique(M, "rows")` fails because of Octave internals and/or memory limitations.

I looked at other posts on finding unique rows, but none of them addressed this issue with large matrices.

My approach now would be to "divide and conquer", e. g. by

```
A(:,:,i)=M(r_i:s_i,:)
B(:,:,i)=unique(A(:,:,i), "rows")
```

with `i` the index of the submatrix, `r_i` and `s_i` the starting and ending row numbers of the submatrices.
To return all the data into one large matrix (and again determine unique rows):

```
C(:,:,i)=B(:,:,i)'
D=reshape(C,l,n*m)
E=D'
F=unique(E, "rows")
```

with `n` the number of submatrices, `m` the original number of rows in a submatrix and `l` the number of columns.

Is there a better way to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Do you care about the order of rows in the output? Does it have to be same as in the input array?

Comment: @Divakar: No, the order of the results does not matter.

Comment: Awesome! So, Andrew's answer posted here must be quite efficient.

Comment: Andrew's answer is also stable with respect to input ordering if you track the rearranged row indexes while you do the sort. :) Negligible memory overhead.

Comment: (Or you can use those tracked indexes to reproduce Matlab's `unique` signature exactly, with the additional outputs. Which could be quite useful.)

Comment: @AndrewJanke Would be a good idea I think to add that to the answer? :)

Comment: Added. And thanks for pointing it out – turns out you *have* to track the mapping indexes to make it efficient. Otherwise you have to sort the entire input each time, which for a matrix radix sort is ugly.

Comment: Have you had a chance to test out these solutions?

Comment: Only the sliding window (tried that first because it was easier to get my head around ;-), not the radix sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a sliding window on columns and use a window size that doesn't cause a memory problem. Here is a solution

```
function A = winuninque(A, winSz)
nCol = size(A,2);
I = zeros(size(A,1), 0);
for k=1:winSz:nCol
    [~, ~, I] = unique([I A(:,k:min(k+winSz-1,end))], 'rows');
end
[~, I] = unique(I);
A = A(I, :);
end
```

### Benchmark

In order to actually have some duplicate rows it's better to generate the matrix with some duplicates, otherwise it will be just sorting. Here is a comparison between different approaches:

```
>> A=repmat(rand(13146,13146), 2, 1);
>> A=A(randperm(end), :);
>> A=A(1:end/2,:);

>> tic; B=rrunique(A); toc
Elapsed time is 13.318752 seconds.
>> tic; C=winunique(A, 16); toc
Elapsed time is 6.606122 seconds.
>> tic; D=unique(A, 'rows'); toc
Elapsed time is 29.815333 seconds.
>> isequal(B,C,D)
ans =
     1
>> size(D)
ans =
        9880       13146
```

Comment: Worked very well on my 13146^2 matrix and also a 16412^2 matrix. So thank you, but before accepting I'll also have to try the others.

Answer (score 6):

#### Radix sort it!

Sounds like you need a memory-efficient sorting algorithm. Unique rows can be found by first sorting the rows, and then checking adjacent rows for duplicates. You could adapt a radix sort for this, sorting on each column in sequence (instead of each digit in sequence). That would be a peak memory cost of sorting one column instead of the entire matrix. Then step through the rows in the sorted result and eliminate duplicates. That's an `O(n)` operation and only needs enough memory to hold two rows.

It can be "stable", too. If you track the rearranged row indexes in addition to the rearranged row values during the process of sorting, you can compute the input-output mapping indexes. (These are the `I` in the signature of Matlab's own `[B,I] = sort(A)`.) That in turn will allow you to rearrange the post-duplicate-removal rows back in to their original order in the input, so you can preserve their order. (Like the `setOrder='stable'` option of Matlab's `unique()`.) They can also be used to calculate the in-out mapping indexes for the overall uniqueness operation, so you can reproduce the full multi-output signature of `unique()`, which can be quite useful.

#### Example code

Here's a basic example implementation. I haven't tested it thoroughly, so don't use it in production without doing your own testing.

```
function A = rrunique(A)
%RRUNIQUE "Radix Row Unique" - find unique rows using radix sort
%
% # Returns the distinct rows in A. Uses the memory-efficient radix sort
% # algorithm, so peak memory usage stays low(ish) for large matrices.

% # This uses a modified radix sort where only the row remapping indexes are
% # rearranged at each step, instead of sorting the whole input, to avoid
% # having to rewrite the large input matrix.

ix = 1:size(A,1); % # Final in-out mapping indexes

% # Radix sort the rows
for iCol = size(A,2):-1:1
    c = A(ix,iCol);
    [~,ixStep] = sort(c);
    % # Don't do this! too slow
    % # A = A(ixStep,:);
    % # Just reorder the mapping indexes
    ix = ix(ixStep);
end    

% # Now, reorder the big array all at once
A = A(ix,:);

% # Remove duplicates
tfKeep = true(size(A,1),1);
priorRow = A(1,:);
for iRow = 2:size(A,1)
    thisRow = A(iRow,:);
    if isequal(thisRow, priorRow)
        tfKeep(iRow) = false;
    else
        priorRow = thisRow;
    end
end
A = A(tfKeep,:);

end
```

When I tested this on a matrix of your size on Matlab R2014b on OS X, it peaked at around 3 GB of memory used, vs about 1 GB to hold just the input matrix. Not bad.

```
>> m = rand([13146,13146]);
>> tic; rrunique(m); toc
Elapsed time is 17.435783 seconds.
```

Comment: You posted an answer! :D

Comment: Perhaps you could include some code to exemplify :)

Comment: You got it - simple (no index tracking) code example added. :)

Comment: I'd give you +10 if I could.... it's been so long since you've posted an answer that I'm tempted to give you a bounty.

Comment: Aw thanks! I kind of took a Stack Overflow break for a while, but I'm back coding Matlab so I've been around recently.

Comment: @AndrewJanke, to test it maybe it's better to create a matrix that actually has duplicate rows, It seems extremely unlikely that you find duplicate rows in `rand([13146,13146])`. Even if it was a binary matrix of that size it would be unlikely.

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia: Agreed. The run with the `rand`s is really just to benchmark the performance, not to test correctness. When writing it I used some small hand-constructed matrixes with dup rows and some NaNs for testing.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea here is same as with [`Andrew's answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29829228/3293881), just the implementation is a bit different at the later stage. So, we sort the rows of the input array bringing the duplicates on top of each other. Then, we run through the rows looking for the duplicates, which can be done efficiently with `diff`. From the `diff` output, we detect `all zeros` rows, which represent those duplicate rows. We create a logical mask out of the *detection* and use this mask to extract the *valid* rows from the input array. Here's the implementation  and this seems to be using half the memory than with **`unique(...'rows')`** -

```
sM = sortrows(M);
out = sM([true ; any(diff(sM,[],1)~=0,2)],:);
```